# Importacion de filtros en angular Js 1.5.8

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

En mi html tengo el codigo el cual llamo el filtro

```
<div class="stream-media" ng-if="'video' == stream.type">
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                        {{ stream.code | trustHtml }} //Esto deberia de funcionar 
                    </div>
                    <div class="stream-media-meta">
                        <a class="title mb5" href="{{stream.url}}" target="_blank">{{stream.title}}</a>
                        <div class="text mb5">{{stream.description}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

En mi Filters.js

```
import {IsUrlFilter} from './filters/is_url.filter';
import {CapitalizeFilter} from './filters/capitalize.filter';
import {HumanReadableFilter} from './filters/human_readable.filter';
import {TruncatCharactersFilter} from './filters/truncate_characters.filter';
import {TruncateWordsFilter} from './filters/truncate_words.filter';
import {TrustHtmlFilter} from './filters/trust_html.filter';
import {UcFirstFilter} from './filters/ucfirst.filter';

angular.module('app.filters')
    .filter('isUrl', IsUrlFilter)
    .filter('capitalize', CapitalizeFilter)
    .filter('humanReadable', HumanReadableFilter)
    .filter('truncateCharacters', TruncatCharactersFilter)
    .filter('truncateWords', TruncateWordsFilter)
    .filter('trustHtml', TrustHtmlFilter)
    .filter('ucfirst', UcFirstFilter);
```

y mi Component.js

```
import { SharedStreamController } from '../../../dialogs/shared_stream/shared_stream.dialog.js';

class StreamPageController{
    constructor(API, DialogService){
        'ngInject';
        this.API = API;
        this.DialogService = DialogService;
    }

    $onInit(){

    }

    list(){

    }

    sharedStreamDialog(){
        let options = {
            controller: SharedStreamController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        }
        this.DialogService.fromTemplate('shared_stream', options);
    }
}

export const StreamPageComponent = {
    templateUrl: './views/app/components/stream-page/stream-page.component.html',
    controller: StreamPageController,
    controllerAs: 'stream',
    bindings: {}
}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: trust_htmlFilterProvider <- trust_htmlFilter
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a mi pregunta era algo sencilla, el filtro que estaba tratando de llamar el cual me daba el siguiente error:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: trust_htmlFilterProvider <- trust_htmlFilter

lo solvente de esta manera añadiendo el codigo

```
export function TrustHtmlFilter($sce) {
    return function(html) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    };
}
TrustHtmlFilter.$inject = ['$sce']; //Esta linea de codigo me ayudo a inyectar el filtro el cual no me lo reconocia de alguna forma no lo hacia
```